# Como exibir as propriedades de um elemento no console com JavaScript puro?

Tags: javascript

Com jQuery eu consigo ver as propriedades de um elemento no console com:

```
console.log($("elemento"));
```

Por exemplo, se eu tenho o elemento abaixo:

```
<input id="nome" type="text" placeholder="Digite aqui">
```

E faço `console.log($("#nome"));`, o console mostra:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Como eu consigo o mesmo resultado com JavaScript puro?**

Tentei com `console.log(document.getElementById("nome"));`, mas retorna apenas o `outerHTML` do elemento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Use `console.dir`

Comment: Funcionou. O que é esse console.dir? Ainda não conhecia

Comment: O console.dir em teoria deveria exibir as propriedades de um objeto de forma interativa, porém no Chrome o console.log faz o mesmo. Como o comportamento do objeto `console` não é padronizado, em cada navegador funciona de uma forma diferente.

Comment: Eu testei no Chrome o console.log e não mostrou, mas o console.dir mostrou. Enfim, obg! Se quiser postar uma resposta, eu marco como certa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para o navegador Chrome, `console.dir` pode ser utilizado para visualizar as propriedades de um elemento do DOM. De acordo com a especificação do `console.dir`, este método deveria funcionar para todos os navegadores, mas em prática a implementação dos métodos do `console` costuma variar de navegador para navegador.

`console.log` no FireFox por exemplo, permite visualizar as propriedades de um elemento, já no Chrome isso não acontece.